# How to calculate whether a point is closer to one curve or another

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vectors, inner-products, curves

I have a curve $y_1=ax^2+bx+c$ and another curve $y_2=dx^2+ex+f$ and a point $(x,y)$. This point is in between both curves and $y_1>y_2$. How do I calculate whether the point $(x,y)$ is closer to $y_1$ or closer to $y_2$?

First solution: I plugged in a given $x$ to find $y_1$ and $y_2$ at that $x$. Then I looked to see if $y_1-y>y-y_2$; if so, then the point is closer to $y_2$, otherwise the point is closer to $y_1$.

Is there any other method to calculate this? Maybe using vectors or inner products?

Comment: Are you measuring distance solely *vertically* ($y$ value), or instead the true Euclidean distance from you point to the nearest point on a curve?

Comment: to the nearest point on the curve. i ned to see whther this point is closer to the first curve or the second. i am not too sure how to about it

Comment: Hi, so the nearest point on a parabola to an external point is the point on the parabola which lies on the normal to the parabola passing through the given external point. Are you able to find normals passing through a given point to a parabola?

Comment: no i don't know how

Comment: Do you know what the general form of the equation of a normal to a parabola looks like? [This](https://www.toppr.com/ask/content/concept/normal-to-a-parabola-207438/#:~:text=Normal%20in%20slope%20form,am%E2%88%92am3.) link may help you.

Comment: To supplement the other comments: there is a non-obvious but learnable method for calculating the true shortest distance from a point to a curve (one would learn about this in the optimization section of a differential calculus course); fortunately for quadratic curves the computations are pretty doable. The easiest general way to answer your question (which curve is closer) is to literally calculate the two distances exactly and then compare.

Answer (score 1):

In a plane, the square of the distance between a point $(x_0,y_0)$ and a parabola
$$y=ax^2+bx+c$$ is given by
$$D^2=(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=(x-x_0)^2+(ax^2+bx+c-y_0)^2\tag 1$$ To obtain the minimum distance, you need to solve for $x$ the simple equation
$$\frac {d\,D^2}{dx}=0$$

Computing and rearranging gives the cubic equation
$$2 a^2 x^3+3 a b x^2+ \left(2 a c-2 a y_0+b^2+1\right)x+(b c-b y_0-x_0)=0\tag 2$$ which does not make any problem. To avoid nasty results and formulae, use the trigonometric solution for three real roots or the  hyperbolic solution for one real root (have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Trigonometric_and_hyperbolic_solutions)); never use Cardano method).

When $(2)$ is solved, go back to $(1)$ to have the distance.

**Example**

Consider the two parabolas
$$y_1=x^2+2x+3 \qquad \text{and} \qquad y_2=4x^2+5x+6$$ and the point $(20,600)$.

So, for the first parabola, we need to solve first
$$2x^3+6x^2-1189x-1214=0$$

Following the steps given in the linked page, we have three reals roots given by
$$x_k=\sqrt{\frac{2390}{3}} \cos \left(\frac{1}{3} \left(2 \pi  k-\cos
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{63\sqrt 3}{1195 \sqrt{2390}}\right)\right)\right)-1$$ with $k=0,1,2$.

Converted to decimals, they are
$$x_1=-25.435022 \qquad x_2=-1.0175732 \qquad x_3=23.452595$$

We do not have to be great wizards saying that $x_3$ is the solution to keep. So, we have $$\large\color{red}{D_1^2=11.92540}$$

Doing the same for the second parabola, we now need to solve
$$32x^3+60x^2-4726x-2990=0$$ Three real roots again
$$x_k=\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{9527}{3}} \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi 
   k}{3}-\frac{1}{3} \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{495\sqrt 3}{9527
   \sqrt{9527}}\right)\right)-\frac{5}{8}$$ which are
$$x_1=-12.823629 \qquad x_2=-0.62932980 \qquad x_3=11.577958$$ Same guess t get

$$\large\color{red}{D_2^2=70.93823}$$

Just conclude and $\cdots\cdots$ check the result !

Comment: is there any other method to solving this?